# Find webform submission ID in a custom submission handler

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform custom submission handler.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state,  WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
  $webform_submission->getDate();
}
```

I am getting all the submitted values except the submission id. How do I get that value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the submission ID in a custom submit handler?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284046/how-can-i-get-the-submission-id-in-a-custom-submit-handler)

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to get the submission ID in a custom submission handler using the following code.

```php
$webform_submission->setSticky(!$webform_submission->isSticky())->save();
$sid = $webform_submission->id();
```

Comment: If you are trying to set a webform submission status via a handler, you should check out the ActionWebformHandler included in the latest dev release of the webform module. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/ActionWebformHandler.php